# Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value Uint8List

Tags: flutter, firebase

Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
Friends, I have indicated the place where the error is below and I tried a few things, but I still could not get rid of this error. Does anyone know the solution?
When I remove ! from _image!, I still get an error.

```
  Uint8List? _image;
    signUpUser() async {
            // set loading to true
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = true;
            });
                String res = await AuthMethods().signUpUser(
                email: _emailController.text,
                password: _passwordController.text,
                username: _usernameController.text,
                bio: _bioController.text,
                gender: _genderController.text,
                file: _image! //--> error);
            if (res == "success") {
              setState(() {
                _isLoading = false;
              });
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
            } else {
              setState(() {
                _isLoading = false;
              });
              // show the error
              showSnackBar(context, res);
            }
          }

selectImage() async {
    Uint8List im = await pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = im;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Could `Uint8List im = await pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);` be causing exception ? Because `pickImage` seems to return nullable and trying to assign `im`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_image` is null. I don't see where you call the `selectImage()` function, and other than that function `_image` is never defined. Even if `selectImage()` was called, when the picker appears the user may not actually pick an image and cancel it or another error can happen. The `AuthMethods().signUpUser()` method seems to not allow the file parameter to be null, that's why when you remove the ! it doesn't work.